# PocketSphinx: Error in decoding

Tags: speech-recognition, raspberry-pi, decoding, cmusphinx

I am getting the error FATAL_ERROR: "batch.c", line 819: PocketSphinx decoder init failed when decoding. It works fine on Sphinx3, but when compiling on Raspberry Pi using PocketSphinx i am getting the error. Kindly help.

Comment: It's better to provide more information from the log, not just the last line. A line above the line you posted contains the reason of failure in plain English.

Comment: ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 334: The word 'SIL' is missing in the dictionary

Comment: This error clearly says you have no entry for the word SIL you defined in grammar. You probably should review your grammar and try to understand what are you doing there.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm about SIX years late, but I had the same problem as yours and the problem was that I didn't have an entity for Silence (SIL) in my dictionary.

Here, is a sample of my dictionary (`ar.dic`):

```
،       SIL
ء       €
آ       € a2
آسف     € a2 s f
أ       €
أبجل    € b j l
```

As you can see, each line represents word-phone pair. The token on the left is the Arabic word, and the token on the right is the word-phone. As you can see, The first entity is the entity for silence.. in Arabic, the punctuation mark "،" is very similar to "," in English which means silence so I used it as a silence!